# Rails, keep anchor tag in devise sign_in stored_location redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Problem is described well [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1334)

extract:

`Given` I am using a Rails app with Devise authentication

`And` I am registered

`But` I am not logged in right now

`When` I visit the path "/path#thing"

`Then` I should see the sign-in form

`When` I sign in

`Then` I should be redirected to "/path#thing"

Answer (score 0):

add a hidden input in your sign in page, for me it was app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.haml

and also some javascript to populate the input:

I called the input `tab_hash`

```
= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f|
  = f.input :login, :hint => true, :required => true
  = f.input :password, :as => :password, :hint => false, :required => true
  = f.input :tab_hash, :as => :hidden
  %div.text-right
    = f.button :submit, t("formtastic.actions.sign_in"), class: 'btn-primary'

.text-center
  %p
  = render :partial => "devise/shared/links"

:javascript
  $(document).ready( function(){
    $("#user_tab_hash").val(window.location.hash);
  });
```

add `attr_accessor :tab_hash` to the User model

in app/controllers/application_controller.rb

add

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    stored = stored_location_for(resource)
    if stored.present?
      stored += params['user']['tab_hash'] # refs #3485 after signing in the tab was lost
    end
    stored || root_url
  end
```